# Why size of stack is small when I use "go stack namestack" in iOS application? - Livecode

Tags: livecode

I have 2 stack.

The first stack is for open the seconds stack by command :

```
go stack namestack
```

This command is for open the seconds stack.This's working fine.It's can open the seconds stack.But It's small after small it's original size.

Here picture:

[image]

[image]

I capture image on iPad.

Comment: Looks like a bug - what version of LiveCode is it?

Comment: My livecode version is 6.7(dp4)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack window opens with incorrect size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905391/stack-window-opens-with-incorrect-size)

Answer (score 0):

Check out "fullscreenmode" in the dictionary...

> Use the fullscreenmode property to choose the most appropriate full
>   screen scaling mode for the application.

Maybe it will help you get the result you are seeking?