# Stack window opens with incorrect size

Tags: ios, livecode

My application has 2 stacks. Stack 1 is "main" and it opens stack 2. Stack 2 is "slideview" and shows an image like an e-book.

My application is for iOS. I test on iPad. I save a standalone application to install on iOS.

I use program "iExplorer" to open a directory ub my app on ipad and copy stack 2 to the "documents" directory.

The script in stack 1 is:

```
on mouseUp
   put specialfolderpath("documents") into rootFolder
   put rootFolder& "/stack2.livecode" into filestack
   go stack filestack
end mouseUp
```

The script in stack 2 is:

```
on preOpenStack
   set the acceleratedRendering of this stack to true
   set the layerMode of image "Image" to "scrolling" 
end preOpenStack
```

This is what I see when I touch the button to open stack 2:

[image: Incorrectly sized stack window]
[image: Correctly sized stack window]

I have captured this image on an iPad.

In stack 2, I use the syntax

```
set the acceleratedRendering of this stack to true
```

If I delete this syntax and touch the button to open stack 2, it's the correct size. What is happening?

Comment: If you just read your question again, you may improve many things. There really is no need to write that your English is bad, after every question. I keep removing irrelevant remarks from your questions.

Comment: Thank you Mark.My English is really bad.

Answer (score 0):

The acceleratedRendering property has been added to help simplify the use of the accelerated rendering features. When set to true, LiveCode automatically configures the compositor properties to the best defaults for the current platform.

When acceleratedRendering is set to true, if the compositorType has not previously been set, the engine configures the compositor properties as follows:

- iOS (non-Retina iPhone): compositorType = OpenGL, compositorTileSize = 32, compositorCacheLimit = 16Mb
- iOS (iPad / Retina iPhone): compositorType = OpenGL, compositorTileSize = 64, compositorCacheLimit = 32Mb
- iOS (iPad Retina): compositorType = OpenGL, compositorTileSize = 64, compositorCacheLimit = 64Mb

Perhaps there is a bug in the compositorTileSize. You can try changing the compositorTileSize:

```
set the compositorTileSize of this stack to 32
```

You need to experiment with the value (32) and see which value is correct: 16, 32, 64, 128 or 256.

Another possibility is that the acceleratedRendering does something to the fullscreenmode and even if it doesn't, the fullscreenmode might be a way to fix this problem.

```
set the fullScreenMode of this stack to exactFit
```

I think that exactFit will do in this case, but you may also try `showAll`or `letterbox`.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Did you try all values for the compositorTileSize? Did you see any changes at all? The fullScreenMode should fix this problem, no matter what. What happens if you test your stack your computer, in the LiveCode IDE? Does the size of the picture change?